# Docker-compose with python command handler

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to the python [cmd library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html) in combination with docker.

```
This is my minimal command class setup.


    
class Commands(cmd.Cmd):
    intro = 'Welcome to the shell.\nType help or ? to list commands.\n'
    prompt = 'Shell: '


    @staticmethod
    def do_stop(arg):
        """
        Stops the servers gracefully
        :param arg:
        :return:
        """
        logger.info("Stopping server...")
        # Do stuff
```

If I start the app without docker, the shell is just working fine. I can interact with it, without issues. However, if I use docker-compose up I get an endless loop of error messages, like in the image below.

[image]

My application main.py looks like the following:

```
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        Commands().cmdloop()
```

Why is docker complaining about an unknown syntax? is something writing to the stdout or stderr, I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
stdin_open: true
```

in the docker compose file, will fix the issue.